# How to add a cancel button for 'contenteditable' editable field?

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

I want to add a cancel button to this editable fields which would make the field non-editable and undo the current changes made.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('save')) {
    alert("Saved!!!");
    $(this).text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text("Save").addClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'true').css({
      'border': 'black solid 1px',
      'outline': 'none'
    }).focus();
  }
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center company">Company Name</div>
<button class="btn btn-default edit">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-default cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modifies you code a bit and then added the click event for your `cancel` button:

```
$('button.edit').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('save')) {
    alert("Saved!!!");
    $(this).text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text("Save").addClass('save');
    $('.company').attr("data-oldText",$('.company').text())
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'true').css({
      'border': 'black solid 1px',
      'outline': 'none'
    }).focus();
  }
});

$('button.cancel').on("click", function() {
  if ($('button.edit').hasClass('save')) {
    $('.company').text($('.company').attr("data-oldText"))
    $('button.edit').text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  }
});
```

I've added `$('.company').attr("data-oldText",$('.company').text())` so when you press `edit` then it "saves" the old data.

Then if you press the `cancel`, it will replace the current text with the old text.

**Working demo**

```js
$('button.edit').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('save')) {
    alert("Saved!!!");
    $(this).text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text("Save").addClass('save');
    $('.company').attr("data-oldText", $('.company').text())
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'true').css({
      'border': 'black solid 1px',
      'outline': 'none'
    }).focus();
  }
});

$('button.cancel').on("click", function() {
  if ($('button.edit').hasClass('save')) {
    $('.company').text($('.company').attr("data-oldText"))
    $('button.edit').text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center company">Company Name</div>
<button class="btn btn-default edit">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-default cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: @Yogapriya No problem, happy to help